# non-basic characters in java, how to handle the encoding correctly

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

when I am trying to call method with parameter using my Polish language f.e.

```
node.call("ąćęasdasdęczć")
```

I get these characters as input characters.

```
Ä?Ä?Ä?asdasdÄ?czÄ
```

I don't know where to set correct encoding in maven pom.xml? or in my IDE? I tried to change UTF-8 to ISO_8859-2 in my IDE setting, but it didn't work. I was searching similiar questions, but I didn't find the answer.

**@Edit 1**

Sample code:

```
public void findAndSendKeys(String vToSet , By vLocator){

    WebElement element;
    element = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(vLocator));
    element.sendKeys(vToSet);

}
By nameLoc = By.id("First_Name");

findAndSendKeys("ąćęasdasdęczć" , nameLoc );
```

Then in input field I got Ä?Ä?Ä?asdasdÄ?czÄ. Converting string to Basic Latin in my IDE helps, but It's not the solution that I needed.

I have also problems with fields in classes f.e. I have class in which I have to convert String to basic Latin

```
public class Contacts{

private static final By LOC_ADDRESS_BTN = By.xpath("//button[contains(@aria-label,'Wybór adresu')]"); 

// it doesn't work, I have to use basic latin and replace "ó" with "\u00f3" in my IDE

}
```

**@Edit 2** - Changed encoding, but problem still exists

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOhXD.png): [image: Changed encoding, but problem still exists]

Comment: You are supposed to use UTF-8 in all conversions. But what does `node.call` do? Eventually, the part that has to have the correct encoding is the input and the output. Since you are using a literal string the input is not a problem (though you should revert the change you made), but what part does the output?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I use this string for input field in Selenium Webdriver

Comment: I think you need to add some more code, and the selenium tag, then. What kind of operation are you doing? What classes are used? If you're opening a web page, what is the declared encoding of that web page? There is not enough context to give a good answer here.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I edited post and added more information, converting to Basic Latin in IDE every string helps, but i am not satisfied with this solution

Comment: @RealSkeptic Literal strings can be a problem if the source code editor (IDE) uses a different encoding to the compiler. Personally I'd set both the IDE and Maven to UTF-8.

Comment: Try  `\u0105` instead of `ą` (in .java) to check that the editor uses the same encoding as the javac compiler. You seem to be receiving UTF-8 but are interpreting it as a single byte encoding. To prevent the operating system interfering, store the text in a file and read it with a programmer's editor like NotePad++ or JEdit that can read with different encodings.

Comment: @biziclop Yes, that's why I said "revert the change you made". OP: please bring your IDE back to UTF-8. If you don't, it will cause you a lot of grief later on when strings misbehave in your project. The solution to this should be programmatic.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Added Screenshot with encoding in my IDE, it didn't solve the problem unfortunately.